# Pyinstaller using matplotlib and reportlab to generate PDFs

Tags: python, pdf, matplotlib, pyinstaller, reportlab

I have a code that uses reportlab to generate a table and matplotlib to generate a graph, then save them as PDF files.  It works perfectly when I run the script through command line, but every time I convert an .exe using pyinstaller, the file refuses to run.  I have tried specifying the path to the hooks, but this seems to do nothing.  I think the problem has to do with creating new PDF files, but the exe file does not run and I have no idea how to address this issue.

```
from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Table, TableStyle
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

doc = SimpleDocTemplate('sample.pdf', pagesize=letter)
# container for the 'Flowable' objects
elements = []
data = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
t=Table(data)
t.setStyle(TableStyle([ ('INNERGRID', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, colors.black),
                        ('BOX', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, colors.black),
                        ('BACKGROUND',(0,0),(-1,0),colors.lightgreen),
                        ('BACKGROUND', (0,1),(-1,1),colors.lightblue),]))
elements.append(t)
# write the document to disk
doc.build(elements)

plt.plot(data[0], data[1])
plt.savefig('Figure.pdf')
plt.show()
```

I tried running test.exe (my file name) on the command line, now I get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "c:\pyfolder\continuum\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_impo
rters.py", line 389, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\reportlab\platypus\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "c:\pyfolder\continuum\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_impo
rters.py", line 389, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\reportlab\platypus\flowables.py", line 32, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "c:\pyfolder\continuum\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_impo
rters.py", line 389, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\reportlab\lib\styles.py", line 28, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "c:\pyfolder\continuum\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_impo
rters.py", line 389, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\reportlab\rl_config.py", line 131, in <module>
  File "site-packages\reportlab\rl_config.py", line 102, in _startUp
  File "site-packages\reportlab\lib\utils.py", line 695, in rl_isdir
AttributeError: 'FrozenImporter' object has no attribute '_files'
```

Comment: Are you sure that your code doesn't generate errors? Check this by calling the .exe file from the command line then you will actually see any error that occur.

Comment: Added the error I get.  Tried this fix by Dude Random21, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35691320/issues-with-pyinstaller-and-reportlab, but did not work.

Comment: I guess then the logical step in this case is to file a bug report at Reportlab or PyInstaller. Guess that PyInstaller would make the most sense as the error only occurs when their package is used.